# How to trigger animation on image after certain scroll offset?

Tags: react-native

How do I trigger an animation to translateY and change height on an Image after a certain offset (e.g. 100) in ScrollView? I'm setting state when scroll direction is down after the offset is reached and using that to determine if I should run my Animated.timing functions but if I use `setState` in `onScroll` my App freezes, probably from setting state too many times but how do I avoid that?

My code for setting state:

```js
onScroll={(event) => {
      const currentOffset = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
      const direction = currentOffset > offset ? 'down' : 'up';
      if (direction === 'down' && currentOffset >= 100 && currentOffset <= 110) setRunAnimations(true)
  }}
```

I'm using the state to run my animations i.e. if true then run this function:

```js
const scrollY = useRef(new Animated.Value(0)).current;

const enlarge = () => {
  Animated.timing(scrollY, {
    toValue: 1,
    duration: 5000,
  }).start();
};

if (runAnimations) enlarge();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid the multiple setStates by checking if runAnimations is false in your onscroll. E.g.

```
onScroll={(event) => {
      const currentOffset = event.nativeEvent.contentOffset.y;
      const direction = currentOffset > offset ? 'down' : 'up';
      if (!runAnimation && direction === 'down' && currentOffset >= 100 && currentOffset <= 110) setRunAnimations(true)
  }}
```

The animation will only run once. However, you could reset the runAnimations at some point.